# Spark Structured Streaming watermark and dropduplicate？

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to dropDuplicate with watermark, the problem is the watermark can't clear sate,
my code is:

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    @transient lazy val log = LogManager.getRootLogger

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[2]")
      .appName("RateResource")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val rateData: DataFrame = spark.readStream.format("rate").load()

    val transData = rateData
      .select($"timestamp" as "wtimestamp",$"value", $"value"%1000%100%10 as "key",$"value"%1000%100/10%2 as "dkey")
      .where("key=0")


    val selectData =transData
      .withWatermark("wtimestamp","20 seconds")  //
      .dropDuplicates("dkey","wtimestamp") 

    val query = selectData.writeStream
      .outputMode("update")
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()

  }
```

and input  records:

```
2017-08-09 10:00:10,10
2017-08-09 10:00:20,20
2017-08-09 10:00:30,10
2017-08-09 10:00:10,10
2017-08-09 11:00:30,40
2017-08-09 10:00:10,10
```

then the first "2017-08-09 10:00:10,10" can output, the second "2017-08-09 10:00:10,10"
can't output after more 10 seconds.

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------+-----+---+----+
|wtimestamp         |value|key|dkey|
+-------------------+-----+---+----+
|2017-08-09 10:00:10|10   |0.0|1.0 |
+-------------------+-----+---+----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+----------+-----+---+----+
|wtimestamp|value|key|dkey|
+----------+-----+---+----+
+----------+-----+---+----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 3
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------+-----+---+----+
|wtimestamp         |value|key|dkey|
+-------------------+-----+---+----+
|2017-08-09 10:00:20|20   |0.0|0.0 |
+-------------------+-----+---+----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 4
-------------------------------------------
+----------+-----+---+----+
|wtimestamp|value|key|dkey|
+----------+-----+---+----+
+----------+-----+---+----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 5
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------+-----+---+----+
|wtimestamp         |value|key|dkey|
+-------------------+-----+---+----+
|2017-08-09 10:00:30|10   |0.0|1.0 |
+-------------------+-----+---+----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 6
-------------------------------------------
+----------+-----+---+----+
|wtimestamp|value|key|dkey|
+----------+-----+---+----+
+----------+-----+---+----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 7
-------------------------------------------
+----------+-----+---+----+
|wtimestamp|value|key|dkey|
+----------+-----+---+----+
+----------+-----+---+----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 8
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------+-----+---+----+
|wtimestamp         |value|key|dkey|
+-------------------+-----+---+----+
|2017-08-09 11:00:30|40   |0.0|0.0 |
+-------------------+-----+---+----+
```

I know watermark drop state by use maxevent-time in window, but in dropduplicate, I don't know how it clear state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operator *dropduplicate* clear state by watermark. As your code,the latest watermark before dropduplicate  is *20 seconds*. So, spark will keep all data from the current maximum time to a 20-second step back which means that the data will be compared with data for the last 20 minutes,and the older data will be clear.